# OpenERP email Sent confirmation message display

Tags: odoo

Please help me to update below given send email method  so as to pop up  depending upon email delivery.

- "Email has been sent"
- "Sorry, Email has not been sent at this point of time

  ## ------------------------------------------------------

  ## Wizard validation and send

  ## ------------------------------------------------------

  ```
  def send_mail(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
  """ Process the wizard content and proceed with sending the related
      email(s), rendering any template patterns on the fly if needed. """
  if context is None:
      context = {}
  ir_attachment_obj = self.pool.get('ir.attachment')
  active_ids = context.get('active_ids')
  is_log = context.get('mail_compose_log', False)

  for wizard in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
      mass_mail_mode = wizard.composition_mode == 'mass_mail'
      active_model_pool_name = wizard.model if wizard.model else 'mail.thread'
      active_model_pool = self.pool.get(active_model_pool_name)

      # wizard works in batch mode: [res_id] or active_ids
      res_ids = active_ids if mass_mail_mode and wizard.model and active_ids else [wizard.res_id]
      for res_id in res_ids:
          # mail.message values, according to the wizard options
          post_values = {
              'subject': wizard.subject,
              'body': wizard.body,
              'parent_id': wizard.parent_id and wizard.parent_id.id,
              'partner_ids': [partner.id for partner in wizard.partner_ids],
              'attachment_ids': [attach.id for attach in wizard.attachment_ids],
          }
          # mass mailing: render and override default values
          if mass_mail_mode and wizard.model:
              email_dict = self.render_message(cr, uid, wizard, res_id, context=context)
              post_values['partner_ids'] += email_dict.pop('partner_ids', [])
              post_values['attachments'] = email_dict.pop('attachments', [])
              attachment_ids = []
              for attach_id in post_values.pop('attachment_ids'):
                  new_attach_id = ir_attachment_obj.copy(cr, uid, attach_id, {'res_model': self._name, 'res_id': wizard.id}, context=context)
                  attachment_ids.append(new_attach_id)
              post_values['attachment_ids'] = attachment_ids
              post_values.update(email_dict)
          # post the message
          subtype = 'mail.mt_comment'
          if is_log:  # log a note: subtype is False
              subtype = False
          elif mass_mail_mode:  # mass mail: is a log pushed to recipients, author not added
              subtype = False
              context = dict(context, mail_create_nosubscribe=True)  # add context key to avoid subscribing the author
          msg_id = active_model_pool.message_post(cr, uid, [res_id], type='comment', subtype=subtype, context=context, **post_values)
          # mass_mailing: notify specific partners, because subtype was False, and no-one was notified
          if mass_mail_mode and post_values['partner_ids']:
              self.pool.get('mail.notification')._notify(cr, uid, msg_id, post_values['partner_ids'], context=context)

  return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
  ```