# OpenERP Email validation

Tags: odoo

Please let me know , how to prevent record getting saved when user enters invalid email address.  Right now system  displays warning message for invalid email address which is as per design but it also saves the record with invalid email address. How can we prevent system saving record with invalid email address

from osv import osv

```
 import smtplib
 import re

  from osv import fields

 class latest_base(osv.osv):
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _name='latest.base'
    _columns={
        'name':fields.char('Name'),

        'image': fields.binary("Image", help="Select image here"),

        'state': fields.selection([
                ('new','New'),
                ('starts','Starts'),
                ('progress','Progress'),
                ('won','Won'),
                ('lost','Lost'), ('tied','Tied')], 'Stage',readonly=True),
        'email':fields.char('Email'),
        }

_sql_constraints = [('unique_name', 'unique(name)', 'Sorry ! A record with the same name already exists.')]


def mymod_new(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'new' })
    return True

def mymod_starts(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'starts' })
    return True

def mymod_progress(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'progress' })
    return True

def mymod_won(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'won' })
    return True

def mymod_lost(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'lost' })
    return True
def mymod_tied(self, cr, uid, ids):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, { 'state' : 'tied' })
    return True


def  ValidateEmail(self, cr, uid, ids, email):
    if re.match("^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", email) == None:
        raise osv.except_osv('Invalid Email', 'Please enter a valid email address')
        return False

 # create method is overridden here

         def create(self, cr, uid,values,context=None):
              if not self.ValidateEmail(cr,uid,[],values['email']):
                   raise ValidateError()
              else:
                   res = super(latest_base,self).create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
                   return res


# write method is overridden here

          def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context=None):
               if not self.ValidateEmail(cr,uid,ids,values['email']):
                   raise ValidateError()
                else:  
                   res = super(latest_base, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context=context)
                   return res 

latest_base()
```

view xml

```
  <field name="email" on_change="ValidateEmail(email)"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your create write and validate functions.I hope your validateemail method is correct.Whenever the re.match is None, then warning will be showed.

```
def  ValidateEmail(self, cr, uid, ids, email):
    if re.match("^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", email) == None:
        raise osv.except_osv('Invalid Email', 'Please enter a valid email address')
    return True

def create(self, cr, uid,values,context=None):
    if 'email' in values:
        self.ValidateEmail(cr,uid,[],values['email'])
    res = super(latest_base,self).create(cr,uid,values,context=context)
    return res

def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context=None):
    if 'email' in values:
        self.ValidateEmail(cr,uid,ids,values['email'])
    res = super(latest_base, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context=context)
    return res
```

Comment: OmaL ,Just replaced with your code and got the result.  :-)

Comment: OmaL , I'm sure that you have the solution for this too.. Please help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015410/openerp-email-sent-confirmation-message-display

Answer (score 1):

Propably you can override the `create` and `write` method to raise a `ValidateError` error for wrong input. References here: https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/api_models/

```
class latest_base(osv.osv):

   def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):
        if not self.ValidateEmail(cr,uid,[],values['email']):
            raise ValidateError()
```

Comment: Hi ,PeterMmm  - May I know where exactly i can see the create and wrtite method. (Sorry , I'm new to OpenERP

Comment: It is in the first link, it is badly formatted and you have to scroll down or search for `create(` .

Comment: Thank for the quick updates I would like to know the path where i can see 'Create' and 'write' method **code** in openerp (version 7.0) application.

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/7.0/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/res/res_partner.py

Comment: Thanks again and here is the latest update after overriding create method in class latest_base. When I entered invalid invalid email address system doesnot saves it and error message is shown which is as per design. ** But system also shows up same error message even for the correct email address** Please let me know the root cause for this issue .  Looks like else clause is required for above mentioned create method ? (again I'm not sure)

Comment: Hi,  further I have overriden  create and write method. and same has been updated in my original post.  Now ' Write  method' works perfectly. However Create method fails with error **in write
KeyError: 'email'**      (Note: if I remove write method, then create method works fine). So may I know the reason why create method fails  when there is code for write method?

Comment: Also I have added screenshot with latest error message by highlighting potentail faulty code line.

Answer (score 0):

This is more easy

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('email@is.valid')
```

Comment: Can you explain this more? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EM = (r"[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$")

def emailvalidation(email):

```
if email:
    EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile(EM)
    if not EMAIL_REGEX.match(email):
        raise ValidationError(_('''This seems not to be valid email.
        Please enter email in correct format!'''))
    else:
        return True
```