# Email Validation in Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

In Leads I have the email field and I want it to be validated and also required fields in form view.

I need to make some configurations in my custom module? Can you give me an example?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042454/openerp-email-validation).

Comment: filed vs. field = typo?

Comment: @PeterWood that question is not what fully answering my question! Because the email field in Leads already existed so I need only to validate it, I do not create a new email field that need to be validated, so is a difference.

Answer (score 2):

In .py file write this method..........

```
import re

def  ValidateEmail(self, cr, uid, ids, email):
    if re.match("^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$", email) != None:
        return True
    else:
        raise osv.except_osv('Invalid Email', 'Please enter a valid email address')
```

In view.xml file write this line

```
<field name="email" on_change="ValidateEmail(email)"/>
```

Comment: I do not have `view.xml` file in my module, where shall I write this `<field name="email" on_change="ValidateEmail(email)"/>` ? I have only `templates.xml` and if I put there I get the following error : `AssertionError: Did not expect element field there, line 21`

Comment: Googling [email regex](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=email+regex) leads to [Stop Validating Emails Addresses With RegEx](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: @PeterWood this is not helping me! And is not answering to may question!